# how to properly create a PDO prepared SQL statement for UPDATE with an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

i am lost trying to figure out how to properly set up a prepared PDO SQL statement when updating an existing record.

my array being passed into my method is such:

```
array(9) { ["catName"]=> string(10) "Kato Marks" ["age"]=> string(2) "40" ["gender"]=> string(6) "Female" ["createTime"]=> string(19) "2017-10-03 03:55:39" ["coloring"]=> string(5) "Black" ["hairLength"]=> string(5) "Short" ["currentMood"]=> string(5) "rowdy" ["weight"]=> string(2) "17" ["hasCatittude"]=> string(1) "0" }
```

with key is the database table column, the value is the database value i wish to update

so far i have the following:

```
public function updateRow($data, $catID)
{
    $db = self::getConnection();

    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET " . implode('= ', array_keys($data).  array_values($data)). " WHERE id='{$catID}'");

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue($key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        return 'Adding new record failed' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

but when i print_r the statement to the screen i get the following:

```
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => UPDATE users SET WHERE id='108' )
```

i am unable to figure out how to properly write the prepared statement, where i dynamically set the table name to the array key, etc. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add : next to the key in the loop.  Also do the same with the implode keys. I'll try and add an answer. I'm unfortunately typing via mobile so it'll take time

Comment: could you show me what the code would look like? i am not following.

Comment: this completely defeats the purpose of PDO when you use `id='{$catID}'`

Comment: I suggest to use a solid query builder. You code could then look like `$this->db->table('users')->where('id', $catID)->update($data);`.

Comment: just for clarification, where does this method belong? is it part of the `User` object?

Comment: this method is part of a Database class

Comment: [How to create a prepared statement for UPDATE query](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/dynamical_update)

Comment: BTW, a function that *returns* an error message is a blaspheme

Answer (score 1):

## Re-evaluate the approach

From your comment, this function belongs in a `Database` class. Admittedly, this class could be used on any table to update any row based on any criteria. However, looking at the function signature, we can see it is supposed to accept a `$catId` parameter, implying it will be used on a very specific table, filtering rows using a specific column.

You could get around this by simply renaming the function and the parameters to more closely represent what it is actually doing but that still wouldn't solve what is, in my opinion, the core of the problem: The object has too many responsibilities.

According to the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), a class "should have one, and only one, reason to be changed". In this case, if a column is added to the `User` table, or that another column needs to be added to the `WHERE` clause, only the `User` class (or Entity) should be affected while the `Database` class should not need any changes.

### Suggestions

For the sake of simplicity, let's imagine a `fridge` database, with a table called `fruits` (I know, very imaginative).

```
create table fruits (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar(20),
    color varchar(20),
    weight int,
    order int, /* order of appearance, say, for a list */
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The php representation of this table would probably look a bit like this

```
class Fruit {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $color;
    private $weight;
    private $order;

    public function __construct($id, $name, $color, $weight) {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->color = $color;
        $this->weight = $weight;
        $this->order = $order;
    }
}
```

Great, now we have a table, and an object that can be used to represent a record of that table. Now we can add a `FruitTable` class that will act as a medium between `Fruit` and the Database itself.

```
class FruitTable {
    private $columns = ['id', 'name', 'color', 'weight', 'order'];
    private $table = 'fridge.fruits';
    private $conn;

    public function __construct($connection) {
        $this->conn = $connection
    }

    public function findOneById($id) {
        /**
         * Query the DB and hydrate a Fruit instance
         */

        return $fruit;
    }
}
```

Now imagine we need to be able to change the `order` field of `Fruit` based on the color of the fruit (I know, this is some really weird business we're working for). No problem, we can add a function to `FruitTable` to make the update.

```
public function updateOrderByColor($newOrder, $color) {
    /* assume proper validation */
    $query = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE fruits SET order = :newOrder WHERE color = :color");
    $query->bindParam(':newOrder', $newOrder);
    $query->bindParam(':color', $color);

    $query->execute();
}
```

This is a very simplistic example, but it shows how much flexibility can be gained over having a simple `Database` class. If a column needs to be added, or a condition changed, there is only one place in the code you need to jump in and mess around with. If there's a problem with a query, there's only one place to look for that bug.

This example isn't perfect, `FruitTable` probably shouldn't have the responsibility of dealing with the database connection directly. You can look at how [Doctrine](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php) and [Eloquent](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php) approach query builders, and how they manage to keep each class encapsulated from the rest.

Comment: Such a rant, without a *hands-on example* can convince little less than noone.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I am both amazed and humbled that someone with such high rep would actually stop and take the time to comment on an answer such as this one. I will take the time to edit as soon as I leave work

Comment: many thanks for this response. you are totally correct. i will work on a better approach and update this question when i have come up with a better solution in a few days. you helped open my eyes on this...

Comment: @YourCommonSense I edited the answer following your comment. Is there anything you think I missed or got wrong?

Comment: I've one objection, instead of initializing a new db connection in the every object, should ope only one connection and to pass it via parameter in all objects created.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your function to something like this.  You first will build your column array, implode it with ', '.  Loop though and bind your variables, then bind your $catID.

```
public function updateRow($data, $catID)
{
    $db = self::getConnection();

    try
    {
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $columns[] = '`' . $key . '` = :' . $key;
        }

        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET " . implode(', ', $columns). " WHERE id=:catID");

        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue($key, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        }

        $stmt->bindValue('catID', $catID, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (\PDOException $e) {
        return 'Adding new record failed' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: `$columns[] = '\`' . $key . '\` = :' . $key;` - What if `$key` contains a space?

Comment: i will offer an edit to your response. pls review and accept if you agree. with my edited code, i do return the correct syntax yet the record is not updating on my end. but i assume that is not related to the $stmt?

Comment: after further review, the actual $catID is not being passed in. i guess it is not binded correctly here `$stmt->bindValue('catID', $catID, PDO::PARAM_INT);` ?